# How to "close" Webview when returning to my activity?

Tags: android, oauth

After authenticating from my app, a new window is shown that later redirects back to the application. Then onNewIntent() is called in my activity. But when select to go back to my app, the twitter web page still shows. Twitter page with a redirect back to the application should not be shown. How do I close the Twitter webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call this method from my activity

```
public void askOAuth(Context context,Handler handler) {
    _msg = new Message();
    _msg.arg1 = AUTHORISE_TWITTER_APP;
    mContext=context;
    this.handler=handler;
    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
    provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
        "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
        "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");//
    //provider.setOAuth10a(true);
    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URL);
    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
}
```

This open a web view(Twitter page that redirect back to my activity).
After this it calls `onNewIntent()` function  of my activity and activity is shown but when I press back button then it again show Twitter page .Now my problem is how to close that twitter page

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to *NOT* launch "authURL" in a new web browser window.  What I prefer to do personally is to launch a new Activity which contains a WebView and pass the URL to that Activity.  That way, it's easier for you to manage navigation within your app during the Oauth authentication process.  So instead of doing this:

```
String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URL);
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
```

I would do this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivityWithAWebView.class);
intent.putExtra("AUTH_URL", authUrl);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your WebView, you can you the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method to get the VERIFIER URL and retrieve your Oauth Verifier.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Is the new window an Activity?  If so, from your main activity, call `startActivityForResult()` and implement the callbacks.

When your callback is triggered you can reload your webview as needed.

You could also restructure your app so that the `onCreate()` of your main activity is smart enough to not show an old result in the webview.